# Having a hard time identifying some FET's in a blown amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, fet, replacement

[image]I'm trying to repair an amp thats protection light stays on full time. Using the a multi meter I've determined the problem to be  2 large FET's on the power supply side of the circuit and 2 smaller FET's on the output side. My problem is I can't find out what kind of FETS the larger 2 are. I've looked up their numbers and found nothing then I got into researching numbering charts for FETs and I think I've figured out it's numbered in the JIS system. However even adding the missing informaiton to the numbers on the FET's I'm unable ot find any information about them. I've included the best picture I could get of them and I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what replacements I need. At this point I'd really just like to know why I can't find any information on them at all as well.

Comment: You've told us absolutely nothing about anything in your question. So far as I can tell it is just a rant about not being able to find something.

Comment: How about some images and the amp model?

Comment: The images didn't upload right the first time for some reason and the amp model is a volfenhag element-5 Z.X-5162

Comment: also @TomCarpenter could you be more specific what other information do you need

Comment: They are not mosfets, they are 2SB778 and 2SD998 power transistors.

Comment: Thank you @HandyHowie that makes more sense to me I was thinking K was part of the part number so I was looking for 2SKB778 which wasn't turning up anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are NPN and PNP power transistors 2SD998 and 2SB778.  Datasheet http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/734001/JMNIC/2SB778_15/+W34Q2_VhlMpEcBVhDEGuzG+/datasheet.pdf

And 
http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/270403/SAVANTIC/2SD998/+Q51W25VPvuCOUlheY/1lHpp+/datasheet.pdf